# Use object with variable name in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I'm new in delphi and i thought it might be safer to swap object names in loop instead of copying whole block for each object. So I need to use variable name as some objects name.
Here is an example of what i tried and what i am trying to do.

```
  Var
    YazGrid: TStringGrid;
```

I defined a variable for grid name as above and i am trying to use like this:

```
  Some Loop
    begin
      if a_variable>=10 then
        YazGrid:=form1.StringGrid1
      else
        YazGrid:=form1.StringGrid2;

      YazGrid.Cells[1,i] := 'SomeText';
    End;
```

As the result- it comes out with the "Access Violation" error. How should i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code, as it appears here, is OK.  You'll need to post some actual code that's causing a problem.

Comment: Thank you @afrazier , I noticed after your comment. Problem was about incrementing row count of one of the grids.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in code that does not appear in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks right in your code.
Make sure that variable "i" in bound. Anyway, even if "i" out-of-bound, this shound't raise Access Violation.

Tested with Delphi XE2 and XE4.

I suppose that error occure in code that not showed in your sample.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i noticed the problem while you were typing this. As you have pointed out, "i" was out of bounds for one of the grids (as rowcount). I'm accepting your answer. I'd be please if you can update/clarify your answer so people can see easily.

Comment: @Mustafa, but assigning value to a cell which has indices out of bounds of the grid won't cause an access violation. Or at least I can't see why it would...